# #each over different models same route

Tags: ember.js

I have two JS arrays, one route, I can only get one model per route and regardless of trying endless ways of creating ArrayControllers and using them I can't use a 2nd model in my template.

e.g.,

```
{{#each}}    // uses content model and default controller... works fine
    <label>{{name}}</label>
{{/each}
{{#each %%whatever%%}}   // trying to use another model/ JS array
    <label>{{name}}</label>
{{/each}
```

Either I get errors or no data shows up.

I've tried specifying the array directly, using an ArrayController and setting its content and/or model to be the JS array. I've tried using `in`...

For example, suppose I have

```
var x = [{name : "Jo"}, {name : "Bob"}];
var y = [{name : "Jake"}, {name : "Ben"}];
```

How can I display them as

```
<label>Jo</label><label>Bob</label>
<label>Jake</label><label>Ben</label>
```

?

(No reduction here, have to use two separate arrays. My example is more complex but the page does not require all out complicating things like creating extra views, templates, and routes)

it would be nice if one could do

```
{{#each x}}  
    <label>{{name}}</label>
{{/each}
{{#each y}}  
    <label>{{name}}</label>
{{/each}
```

but this doesn't work.

Any ideas, this is driving me crazy! (I know I could add a variable to each element that specifies which collection it part of then use #if but this is too much of a hack and not very convenient)

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setupController hook in your Route to set properties on the controller. These controller properties are then rendered by the template.

```
// define some arrays
App.x = [{name: "Jo"}, {name: "Bob"}];
App.y = [{name: "Jake"}, {name: "Ben"}];

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        // make these available to the controller
        controller.set('x', App.x)
        controller.set('y', App.y)
    }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/n724p/

Comment: The problem is using capital letters!! http://jsfiddle.net/Dx3aJ/ Simply changing `y` to `Y` breaks the code!!! That really sucks!!!! Wasting a whole day trying to get things to work ;/

Comment: This is an unfortunate gotcha of the naming conventions ember uses.  If you use capital letters Ember assumes the object is in the global namespace.  See this answer for more information  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772924/emberjs-text-binding-not-working/22774957#22774957